# How does SMTP servers authenticate to each other

Tags: email, smtp

As a regular user, to send email through a SMTP server, e.g. gmail, I need to authenticate.
However when gmail send an email received from its user, to a different domain, e.g. outloom.com, it also uses SMTP, right?

In that case, how is authentication done? I don't think there is any username/password used...
Does the receiving server just rely on SPF and DKIM? What if the sending server didn't set those things up?

Comment: “Does the receiving server just rely on SPF and DKIM?” Yup. “What if the sending server didn't set those things up?” Mail sent that way is considered spam.

Comment: SMTP has been around a while and is very well documented. What research have you done on this topic prior to asking here?

Comment: I have exactly the same question!